# Reading batches from a list wrapping around

Tags: python

I have the following situation. Say I have a variable `batch_size` and a list called `data`. I want to pull `batch_size` elements out of `data`, so that when I hit the end I wrap around. In other words:

```
data =[1,2,3,4,5]
batch_size = 4
-> [1,2,3,4], [5,1,2,3], [4,5,1,2], ...
```

Is there some nice idiomatic way of returning slices like this? The start index is always `batch_size * batch` modulo the length of `data`, but is there a simple way of "wrapping around" from the beginning if `batch_size * (batch+1)` goes beyond the length of the list? I can of course patch together two slices in this case, but I was hoping that there's some really clean way of doing this.

The only assumption I'm making is that `batch_size < len(data)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.cycle` and the `grouper` recipe from itertools

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
batch_size = 4
how_many_groups = 5

groups = grouper(itertools.cycle(data), batch_size)
chunks = [next(groups) for _ in range(how_many_groups)]
```

The result of chunks is then:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (5, 1, 2, 3),
 (4, 5, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 5, 1),
 (2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

So if you actually need those as lists, you'll have to cast it as such (`[list(next(groups)) for ...]`)

Comment: Cool ! even shorter than python!

Answer (score 2):

You can, also, use `deque` from `collections` module and do one rotation over the deques like this example:

```
from collections import deque

def grouper(iterable, elements, rotations):
    if elements > len(iterable):
        return []

    b = deque(iterable)
    for _ in range(rotations):
        yield list(b)[:elements]
        b.rotate(1)


data = [1,2,3,4,5]
elements = 4
rotations = 5
final = list(grouper(data, elements, rotations))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than my answer! I should reach for deques more often.

Comment: Your answer is good too. I've just added another way to do the trick. The first and the quick way to solve the OP question is by using `itertools.cycle()`. And `deque` with custom method can do the same trick too.

Comment: @AdamSmith for me the `it.cycle()` approach was orders of magnitude faster. Creating a full list and then slicing is relatively expensive. Perhaps `islice` could improve it.

Comment: @AChampion, Yes please if you have any suggestions let me know i'll test them and i'll modify my current answer. I can make a benchmark too. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I shave a half of the time off with `yield list(itertools.islice(b, elements))` but it is still 3 times slower than `itertools.cycle()`

Comment: Also you assume you just have to `rotate(1)` it is probably better to `rotate(-elements)` to be more general, e.g. if `data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` you would expect `[1,2,3,4], [5,6,1,2], ...`, not `[1,2,3,4], [6,1,2,3], ...`

Comment: If i follow the OP's question, with `data=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `n =5` the output will be `[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,1,2,3,4],...]`. This is a special case here with the OP question. However, a general answer would be like you said `rotate(-elements)`. I'll do the benchmark and i'll update my answer. Thanks for your comments.